# Using the (x%y) in python

Tags: python

Why in python the x%y result is x when x is less than y. should the result be zero?
for example when I try 4%5, python give me 4 as a result of and I believe it should be zero

Comment: No, it's the remainder in integer division. 4/5 is 0, and the remainder is 4.

Comment: x fits 0 times in y, therefore with a remainder of x

Comment: ```x % y``` will give you the remainder when ```x``` is divided by ```y```

Comment: Why would it be zero? What do you think `%` means?

Comment: You're confusing the `%` operator with the division operator.  The `%` operator is a remainder operator.  `x % y` evaluates to `x - y * (x // y)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

% -> refers to the ***modulo operator***
So you would get the remainder if you use this operator
4%5 will give 4 as 4 is the remainder when you divide 5 by 4
***If you wish to get the quotient then you can use // which is used for absolute division***
so 4%5 gives 4
and 4//5 gives 0

Answer (score 0):

The `%` symbol in Python is called the Modulo Operator.
**It returns the remainder of dividing the left hand operand by right hand operand.** It's used to get the remainder of a division problem.

Example:

```py
5%6
# results in 5
```

See the long division below

```
_____0__
6  | 5
   | 0
   |_____
   | 5
```

Performing `5 / 6` results in reminder of `5`, thus `5%6` is `5`